# Follow up email when hiring manager doesn't call

Tags: professionalism, job-search, follow-up

When a peer at another company forwards your resume to a hiring manager, and the hiring manager doesn't get in touch, how should one follow up with the peer?

It's possible that however qualified your peer may have found you, the hiring manager was not impressed. However, in the event that there was an oversight a follow-up might correct, it seems that a single and tactful follow up email with the peer might be in order.

Do you agree? And, if so, how might one best word such a tactful email.

Answer (score 1):

You could say something very simple along the lines of:

> Hi ${PEER},
>
> I haven't heard back from the hiring manager at your company. Have you heard anything?
>
> Thanks,
>   ${ME}

I used this sort of format before, and it works. The person you're communicating with is someone who knows you, so you probably don't need to worry about really formal language. If they *have* heard something (good or bad), they'll probably let you know, even if the hiring manager didn't let you know. If they haven't heard anything, they'll probably say that too.

I haven't actually asked someone *explicitly* to go a speak with the hiring manager and get a detailed answer. I assume that my friends know if they can do that or not, and they will, if possible. Of course, whether or not you feel you need to do this this might also depend who your friends are.

Answer (score 0):

I would say **no**.

For legitimate or non-legitimate reasons, the hiring manager has not gotten back to you. That's okay.

A company that wants to hire quality people and that isn't stuck in a morass of mismanagement and red tape will be able to make you an offer fairly quickly. As in, within a day or three.

Years ago, I was flown out to `[city]` to interview at `[Acme]`. On my own, I arranged for an additional interview at `[Frobozz]` later the same day. I originally wanted to work for Acme and thought of Frobozz as a backup. *Frobozz made an offer that very day.* I accepted, because a bird in the hand, etc.

Three weeks later, Acme made an offer. I gently turned them down (no sense in rubbing their face in it). Ironically, years later Acme was bought by another company and both tanked.

The point is that on that day, I had one offer from Frobozz and **no** offer from Acme, so the choice was obvious. Right now, **you have no offer**. You can pursue this non-offer, or you can look for that company that wants to hire you **today**. Which choice makes the most sense?

---

*Never, ever apply at only one place and think your work is done for the day. Why? Because you don't even know if that company even has a position and/or budget! I've had several verbal offers over the years that evaporated because budgets changed, reorgs happened, etc.