# Following up with Hiring manager before the interview

Tags: follow-up

I read through a couple of follow up related questions at the Workplace like [follow-up position status](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p) and [following-up with Hiring manager](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31896/follow-up-email-when-hiring-manager-doesnt-call). They are related to post interview follow-up. I am interested to understand pre-interview follow-up. Here is my situation:

I had contacted a hiring manager regarding a position in their department. In her reply she mentioned I had the skill set required, asked for my CV and would want to meet me once she is in the country after four days. I did send my resume and followed up after four days. I did not get a response from her for two weeks since the initial communication. I understand it is a catch-22 situation, but for this situation, should I follow up with the hiring manager without risking my chances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were in your shoes, I would follow-up at this point and phrase my communication as to incite an answer, be it negative or positive.

You may want to say something like:

> Per our last e-mail exchange, I would be interested in participating in an interview for the position we discussed. I would be available for an interview on Monday October 5th at 09:00 but I have also additional availability in that same week or the following that may be more convenient to you. Would this time slot work for you or would you rather conduct the interview at another time.

This may sound aggressive for some but this type of communication are helping the recipient take action and help you close the sale. You are actually helping her with the overall process because if she is interested in an interview, she will have to come up with a date and time for it and you are acting as a catalyst.

I don't believe this would jeopardize your chances as she has probably made a decision one way or another but simply did not communicate it to you.